# driver.page_source returns a blank string

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I need to save the entire html source into a file, for parsing later.

It seems I am missing something obvious here, but the code is supposed to get the page source and save it to a text file. All it does is create an empty file. IF i write a static string, it gets saved. so i suspect it's because, the page_source is coming up blank.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time 
# imported keys tp try Enter key simualtion.
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
#driver.set_window_size(2000, 1500)
driver.get("http://www.moneycontrol.com")
searchText = driver.find_element_by_id("search_str")
searchText.send_keys("dlf")
search_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn_black.btn_search.FR")
search_button.click()
time.sleep(3)# i know this isn't the right way to wait. 
StrSource = driver.page_source
textfile = open('test1.txt', 'w')
textfile.write(StrSource)
textfile.close()
```

Comment: Seems a Python Client issue with Unicode encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Add an implicit wait in order to allow the driver to wait for all page elements to load completely.

```
 driver = webdriver.Firefox()   
 driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

if that doesn't work , then add an **explicit wait** for any element on target page.
Add an Assert to check if the the target page is loaded completely. Then start scraping the page source to text file.

Answer (score 0):

I have run your own script. The control flow is pretty good till we hit the line:

```
textfile.write(StrSource)
```

While trying to write within `test1.txt` **`Selenium-Python`** Client shows error as :

```
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 57354-57358: character maps to <undefined>
```

It is a known issue with **`Selenium-Python`** Client v3.7.0 and we are expecting a fix sooner.

Comment: Can i store after encoding maybe in utf-8? Can you suggest any work-around?